# Can the vertex size be reduced when importing a GML-formatted graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have got a graph in GML format (see attachment). I imported it on the *Mathematica*.

```
g=Import["~/K33_2.gml ", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

With the guarantee that its layout will not change, I want to reduce the size of the vertices. I tried to change them with `VertexSize`. But it doesn't work. (`Graph[g, VertexSize -> 0.01 ]`)

[image]

---

I don't find an interface for attachment uploads on this platform. So I pasted the text as below.

**K33_2.gml**

```
  graph
[
    hierarchic  1
    label   ""
    undirected  1
    node
    [
        id  1
        label   "b1"
        graphics
        [
            x   540
            y   640
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#0000FF"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "b1"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  2
        label   "b2"
        graphics
        [
            x   600
            y   320
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#0000FF"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "b2"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  3
        label   "r1"
        graphics
        [
            x   660
            y   160
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#FF0000"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  4
        label   "r2"
        graphics
        [
            x   300
            y   320
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#FF0000"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  5
        label   "r3"
        graphics
        [
            x   1080
            y   0
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#0000FF"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  6
        label   "x6"
        graphics
        [
            x   900
            y   80
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#D228C2"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "x6"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  7
        label   "x7"
        graphics
        [
            x   540
            y   240
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#D228C2"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "x7"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  8
        label   "b3"
        graphics
        [
            x   360
            y   400
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#0000FF"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "b3"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    node
    [
        id  9
        label   "x9"
        graphics
        [
            x   540
            y   720
            w   30.0
            h   15.0
            type    "ellipse"
            raisedBorder    0
            fill    "#D228C2"
            outline "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "x9"
            color   "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            anchor  "c"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  3
        target  6
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  9
        target  4
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  3
        target  2
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  7
        target  4
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  1
        target  5
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  6
        target  1
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  5
        target  6
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  6
        target  2
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  2
        target  7
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  3
        target  7
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  7
        target  8
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r1"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  8
        target  4
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  1
        target  9
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r2"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  8
        target  9
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
    edge
    [
        source  9
        target  5
        graphics
        [
            fill    "#000000"
        ]
        LabelGraphics
        [
            text    "r3"
            fill    "#FFFFFF"
            fontSize    12
            fontName    "Dialog"
            configuration   "AutoFlippingLabel"
            contentWidth    36
            contentHeight   20
            model   "centered"
            position    "center"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: you could reset by pattern: Graph[g, VertexSize -> {_ -> .01}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each vertex has a size set separately. Thus changing the global `VertexSize` of the graph will have no effect. One solution would be to set a new size for each vertex, but this is not nice. Instead, we first remove all `VertexSize` settings, then re-add a global one:

```
Annotate[AnnotationDelete[g, VertexSize], VertexSize -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get the property of the size of all the vertices of a graph?

Comment: `AnnotationValue[g, VertexSize] `  seems to work, but I don't see what the output  means.  `{1 -> {30., 15.}, 9 -> {30., 15.}, 4 -> {30., 15.}, 2 -> {30., 15.}, 
 5 -> {30., 15.}, 8 -> {30., 15.}, 3 -> {30., 15.}, 7 -> {30., 15.}, 
 6 -> {30., 15.}}`

Comment: `1 -> {30, 15}` means that vertex `1` is 30 units wide and 15 units tall.